# If $\sum a_n/k^n = 0$ for all $k$, then $a_n = 0$ for all $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that the sum from $n=1$ to infinity of $a_n/k^n$ is zero, for all k=1,2,3,... That is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{k^n}=0, k=1,2,3,...$$
 Prove that $a_n=0$ for all n.

I want to use the identity theorem I think (it seems like it might work here), but I can't see how to apply it in this situation. Could anyone help with this please?

Comment: "I want to use the identity theorem I think" **Yes**. $f(z) = \sum a_nz^n$.

Comment: Hint. $0$ is an accumulation point for $\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: i can't quite see how to express my solution - what is the zero set f^(-1)(0)? Is it just 1/k? And also can we just assume that the power series is holomorphic?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{a_n }{2^n } =0 $ we obtain that $|a_n |<2^n $ for large $n .$
Hence the power series $$ G(z) =\sum_{j=0}^{\infty } a_n z^n $$ defines a holomorphic function  in the disc $\{z :|z| <\frac{1}{2} \} .$
Hence we can use the identity theorem.