# Sequence $\{u_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ - Complex analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Let $\{u_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ a sequence of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum_{n
>  \geq 0} |u_n|$ converge and $\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{u_n}{2^{nk}}=0$ for
>   $k=1,2,3, \dots$. Compute $u_n$.

**Solution :** As $\sum_{n\geq 0} |u_n|$ converge, then $|u_n| \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$, i.e. $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|u_n|=0 \implies u_n=0$ for each $n > N$. Hence $\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{u_n}{2^{nk}}= \sum_{n =0}^N \frac{u_n}{2^{nk}}=0$. It is at this stage that I have a little problem. I think we have to consider the power serie $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\sum_{n =0}^N \frac{u_n}{2^{nk}})x^k$, but it is very unclear.

Is anyone could help me at this point?

For your information, we have seen in class this week some theorem like Cauchy inequality, Liouville, Taylor theorem, .... (related to power series)

Thanks!

Comment: That $\;|u_n|\to 0\;$ doesn't mean that $\;u_n=0\;$, not even sometimes.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @george $|u_n|=\left|(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n}\right| \to 0$ but $u_n\neq 0$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. If you want me to include $n=0$, replace $n$ with $n!$ and it still holds, with the definition $0!=1$.

Comment: @george Many. $\;u_n=\frac1{n^k}\;$ , for any $\;k>1\;$ , or $\;u_n=q^n\;$ , for any complex $\;q\;$ with $\;|q|<1\;$

Comment: Ok, but what could I do instead of my trial?

Comment: Are you able to show that $u_0$ must be zero (by considering arbitrarily large $k$)?

Comment: This question seems to be relevant, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580474/if-sum-a-n-kn-0-for-all-k-then-a-n-0-for-all-n

Comment: @EricTowers Could you give me a result a can use to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = \sum_{n \ge 0} |u_n|$. Then for any integer $k \ge 1$, $|u_0| = |\sum_{n \ge 1} u_n/2^{kn}| \le A/2^k$.

This implies that $u_0=0$. If it isn't then we can pick an integer $k > \log_2 (A/|u_0|)$ and find that $|u_0| < |u_0|$ which is a contradiction.

Once you know that $u_0=0$, you get that for any integer $k \ge 1$, $|u_1| = |\sum_{n \ge 2} u_n/2^{kn}| \le A/2^{2k}$, which implies $u_1 = 0$, and so on.

Comment: Could you explain in details how you found $|u_0| < |u_0|$?

Comment: $|u_0|  <\ \frac{A}{2^k} \implies 2^k < \frac{A}{|u_0|} \implies k< \log(\frac{A}{|u_0|})$, so there is a mistake in your solution (Example $2^2 < 5 \not\implies  2 >\log_2 (5) \approx 2,32192$)

Comment: we care about the opposite inequality : when $k > \log_2(A/|u_0|)$ you have $A/2^k < |u_0|$, hence by transitivity you get $|u_0| \le A/2^k < |u_0|$

Comment: I don't understand you : "we care about the opposite inequality"... by my argument we can use $k > \log_2(A/|u_0|)$. Could you explain in details what do you mean?

Comment: Suppose we have a sequence where $A = 30$ and that someone tells you that $|u_0| = 2$.You want to tell him that this is impossible because you know that for every integer $k$, $|u_0| \le A/2^k$. To do this you pick a large $k$ and use it to get an upper bound for $|u_0|$ that is smaller than $2$.It turns out that $\log_2(30/2) = \log_2(15) = 3.9...$ so you can pick $k=4$. Now you tell him "I just have to apply the result with $k=4$ and I get $|u_0| \le 30/2^4 = 30/16 = 1.875 < 2$, so you must be wrong". And you can say something like this for ANY positive number he thinks $u_0$ may be.

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong... We have $u_0=0$; if not, consider $|u_0|=l \not = 0$. However we have $l \leq \frac{A}{2^k} \to 0$ when $k \to \infty$. Hence , it suffices to take $0<\epsilon<l$ and there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\frac{A}{2^k}| = \frac{A}{2^k} < \epsilon$ once $k>N$ ... $\implies l \leq \frac{A}{2^k} < \epsilon \implies l < \epsilon $ (contradiction)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}u_n z^n$ for $|z|<1 .$ Then $f(z)$ exists and is analytic on the open unit disc $D$ because $|z|<1\implies |u_n z^n|\leq  |u_n|,$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0}|u_n|<\infty.$ We have  $f(2^{-k})=0$ for $k\in N.$

An analytic function on $D$ that takes the same value on an infinite set $S=\{z_k:k\in N\}$ when $\lim_{k\to \infty}z_k \in D,$ must be a constant function. So $f=0.$ Since $n!u_n$ is the $n$th derivative of $f$ at $0,$ we have $u_n=0$ for all $n.$